# Piping and redirect in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a script that takes the piped output of whatever hits it (this script will always the be the last script run), saves it to a temp file, then deletes the temp file as the last line of the script.

Example:

```
cat blah | ./scripta.sh | ./anotherscript.sh | ./yetanotherscript |./finalscript
```

The problem is that we do not always run all the scripts at once.  Once it could be this:

```
cat blah | ./anotherscript.sh | ./finalscript.sh
```

or

```
cat blah | ./anotherscript.sh | yetanotherscript.sh | ./finalscript.sh
```

etc...

The script, after it grabs that data as a file named moo will process it like this

```
awk < moo 'NR%20==0 {print "\nYear  Eng Disp. Cyl  City FE  Hwy FE    Model\n" } {print}  END{ print "total lines: " NR}'
```

Is it permissible to then add

```
rm -r \file\path\to\where\is\moo
```

as the last line?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Which of the scripts in the pipeline do you want to add this command to? Why is `moo` different from `blah`?

Comment: I think that's a very bad design decision. Your scripts should read from stdin and write to stdout. Only. You need to ensure your scripts are not so tightly coupled -- otherwise, they should be one program with options for running functions (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the 'awk' utility reads from standard in, so you can just put this in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR%20==0 {print "\nYear  Eng Disp. Cyl  City FE  Hwy FE    Model\n" } {print}  END{ print "total lines: " NR}'
```

You can even write an executable awk script and pipe to that:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

NR%20==0 {
  print "\nYear  Eng Disp. Cyl  City FE  Hwy FE    Model\n"
} 

{
  print
}

END { 
  print "total lines: " NR
}
```

Using this method, it sounds as if you have no need for a temporary file of any kind.  However if you did, you could just as also do:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /tmp/tmpfile.txt

# Do some things with the file.

rm /tmp/tmpfile.txt
```

Comment: Your first script could just run awk, without the `cat |`, and would have precisely the same behavior (and slightly better performance).

Comment: Good point, also added that you can write executable awk scripts.  All good info for the OP.